# AWS Lambda and Abstract classes - RequestHandler

Tags: java, aws-lambda, abstract-class, java-11, pojo

I have a general question about AWS lambda and abstract classes in Java.

I've recently upgraded an AWS lambda project to Java 11 and now my `handleRequest` call is getting the response

```
"{}"
```

It **seems** to be due to my output object being an abstract class as we return different children objects depending on business logic.

```
MyLambdaClass implements
    RequestHandler<InputObject, OutputAbstractObject>
```

My question is, how come this is now an issue with Java 11.  I'm aware I can use `RequestStreamHandler` and do the serialisation myself but ideally I'd like to keep as much code the same with the upgrade.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey OP - welcome to Stack Overflow. Did anything about your code change, or is it exactly the same other than the upgrade to Java 11? An abstract class shouldn't cause your returned object to be empty; there's nothing about an abstract class that prevents Lambda from serializing it (deserializing it may well be more difficult)

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems AWS changed some details of how they serialize JSON in the Java 11 runtime, but I was not able to find any documentation for the change.

I am working around it with a custom `RequestStreamHandler`, as you suggest.